# image caption generator

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, image-processing

I see two models of image caption generator online:

[image]

In the above model, the first LSTM cell of decoder takes the entire image as an input.

[image]

In the above model, all the LSTM cells of the decoder take the entire image as an input.
Which of the two methods is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single canonical captioning model, or a "correct" way to do image captioning. That's like asking whether logistic regression or SVM is the correct method to solve a binary classification task. It is possible that both models are capable of solving whatever image captioning task you might have in mind.